# URLSession in loop not working

Tags: swift, for-loop, urlsession

I am trying to downlod multiple JSON files with a URLSession and when I run the funtion one time it works. But the moment I call the `getSMAPrices` function from a loop it does not work and I can not find out why.

Here is the working download function that works if i call it.

```
func getSMAPrices(symbol: String) {
    let urlString = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SMA&symbol=\(symbol)&interval=daily&time_period=9&series_type=close&apikey=KPLI12AW8JDXM77Y"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }

    dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        //Implement JSON decoding and parsing
        do {
            //Decode retrived data with JSONDecoder and assing type of Article object

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            let stockData = try decoder.decode(SimpelMovingAvarage.self, from: data)

            //Get back to the main queue
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(stockData)
            }

        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }

        })
    dataTask?.resume()
}
```

And here is my very simple loop that replaces a part in the URL every run cycle. But nothing happens.

```
public func scanSymbols() {
    for symbol in self.symbols {
        progress += 1
        progresBar.maxValue = Double(symbols.count)
        progresBar.doubleValue = progress

        //This does not work
        getSMAPrices(symbol: symbol.key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work" and "nothing happens".

Comment: nothing gets printed to the console from the loop

Comment: Use the debugger and see what your code is doing.

Comment: Also note that your loop will finish immediately while all of the sessions attempt to run in the background.

Comment: Thanks never actualy used the debuger but i found the problem. There where quotation marks in my strings dat should not be there so the url was invlid.

Comment: You should delete this question then.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `dataTask` variable appears to be an instance property and is getting overwritten every time you call this method.

Comment: You should read the comments. The OP already stated what the issue was.